# Find a specific key in python dictionary inside a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I am looking to get a specific key at a certain index

```
[
   {
      "id":"23fr3yf48",
      "type":"engine",
      "details":{
         "text":"New",
         "type":"SPT_2048",
         "id":"7033_Q-156",
         "engine_details":{
            "dateCreated":"2021-08-13 08:59:32.870953+00:00",
            "createdBy":"John",
         },
      },
      "confirm":true
   },
   {
      "id":"3u823983hf",
      "type":"wheel",
      "details":{
         "text":"Old",
         "type":"SPT_0006",
         "id":"101841_2004497"
      },
      "confirm":true
   },
]
```

In this JSON I want to get the 'id' inside 'details' dict. I specifically want to get the 'details' from the index 1 that has id - '101841_2004497' skipping the 0th index. I want to know to iterate through the list and find the specific index. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried, and where exactly does it fail to give you the expected result?

Comment: If you want to iterate through, you need at least a key to know you've reached the correct element, "3u823983hf" for instance. If you only want to access "101841_2004497", you can use : `data[1]["details"]["id"]`

Comment: @TitouanL what if there is another object "details" at the 2nd index with a different id and I want to print both?

Comment: That's what the 1st part of my comment is about, 'How do you know you want the 2nd and 3rd element and not the 1st ?' You need to know what is specific about them in order to iterate through the list and find these specificities, otherwise, the only solution is to hardcode `data[2]["details"]["id"]` as well ...

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple for loop to check each item in list if the id of its details is equal to the value which you mentioned: 101841_2004497

```
for item in list:
    if item["details"]["id"] == "101841_2004497":
        print(item["details"])
```

JSON response:

```
{'text': 'Old', 'type': 'SPT_0006', 'id': '101841_2004497'}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to iterate through the list - you can directly access an item by its index. See, for example [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).